# Ruby sum stdin integers

Tags: ruby, stdin

I have:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

Suppose you have a sequence of integers `1..n` a ruby novice would sum the sequence like so:

```
$ ruby -e 's=0
     for i in 1..500000
        s+=i
     end
     puts s'
125000250000
```

Now suppose that I have the same sequence that comes from the `stdin`:

```
$ seq 1 500000 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{s=0}
                            s+=$_.to_i
                            END{puts s} '   
125000250000
```

So far so good.

Now increase the terminal value from 500,000 to 5,000,000:

```
$ ruby -e 's=0
         for i in 1..5000000
            s+=i
         end
         puts s'
12500002500000   <=== CORRECT

$ seq 1 5000000 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{s=0}
                             s+=$_.to_i
                             END{puts s} '
500009500025     <=== WRONG!
```

It produces a different sum.

`awk` and `perl` both produce the correct result with the same sequence:

```
$ seq 1 5000000 | awk '{s+=$1} END{print s}'
12500002500000
$ seq 1 5000000 | perl -nle '$s+=$_; END{print $s}'
12500002500000
```

Why is ruby producing the incorrect sum? I don't think it is overflow since `awk` and `perl` are working correctly on the same input.

---

**Conclusions:**

Thank you David Aldridge for diagnosing this.

1. OS X and BSD `seq` converts to a float output at 1,000,000 while GNU `seq` supports arbitrary precision integers. OS X `seq` is useless as a source of integers greater than 1,000,000. Example on OS X:

   ```
   $ seq  999999 1000002
   999999
   1e+06
   1e+06
   1e+06
   ```
2. The ruby method `.to_i` silently converts a partial string to an integer and that was the 'bug' in this case. Example:

   ```
   irb(main):002:0> '5e+06'.to_i
   #=> 5
   ```
3. The 'correct' line in the script is to either use `$_.to_f.to_i` to use floats or to use `Integer($_)` to not have the script fail silently. `awk` and `perl` parse 5e+06 into a float, and `ruby` does not implicitly:

   ```
   $ echo '5e+06' | awk '{print $1+0}'
   5000000
   $ echo '5e+06' | ruby -lne 'print $_.to_i+0'
   5
   ```
4. And thanks to Stefan Schüßler for opening a Ruby [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13693) regarding `.to_i` behavior.

Comment: FYI, I've opened a [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13693) for this issue.

Comment: FWIW Ruby 2.4 Enumerable#sum method is optimized for this, so `(1..5000000).sum` returns almost instantly.

Comment: May I ask why the down vote so that I may either correct this question or future questions? Was there something unclear or not useful here for other Ruby novices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a 100% answer, but I notice that:

```
seq 500000 500001 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{}
                             puts $_
                             END{} '
500000
500001
```

... but ...

```
seq 5000000 5000001 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{}
                             puts $_
                             END{} '
5e+06
5e+06
```

... so the "relaxed" approach that #to_i takes to converting the values to integers will still work ...

```
seq 5000000 5000001 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{}
                             puts $_.to_i
                             END{} '
5
5
```

... but the more strict #to_int will not

```
seq 5000000 5000001 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{}
                             puts $_.to_int
                             END{} '
-e:2:in `<main>': undefined method `to_int' for "5e+06":String (NoMethodError)
```

Edit: I also notice:

```
seq 5000000 5000001

5e+06
5e+06
```

So an `-f` flag has to be passed to seq to get integer format.

Edit again:

final answer:

```
seq -f %f 1 5000000 | ruby -lne 'BEGIN{s=0}
                                  s+=$_.to_i
                                 END{puts s} '

12500002500000
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's it.

Comment: You could also do `seq 1 5000000  | tail` :)

Comment: And to overcome this, one could use `s+=$_.to_f.to_i`

Comment: I think this is correct. How to maintain arbitrary precision of arbitrary precision that Ruby supports though?

Comment: I wish I could work out why $_ is reading the last line read as a string conversion in exponential format. It's like something Excel would do.

Comment: It could be interesting to test on FreeBSD, I believe there is a FreeBSD version of `seq` in MacOS and it for unknown reason behaves that way. Also, would you mind to try `alias | grep seq`?

Comment: @mudasobwa `alias | grep seq` no result

Comment: OK, after some investigation I got FreeBSD’s `seq` _always_ uses `%g` format (as by [tag:c]’s `format`.) GNU/Linux guesses the format basing on arguments.

Comment: `to_int` doesn't work, because that methods doesn't exist (hence the `NoMethodError`). The correct method is `Integer($_)`, which results in `ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "5e+06"`

Answer (score 1):

To explain the e-notation output, the OS X man page for [`seq`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/seq.1.html) gives some insight:

> Use a *printf(3)* style **format** to print each number. [...] The default is `%g`.

Therefore, `seq`'s output is equivalent to Ruby's:

```
sprintf('%g', 100000)
#=> "100000"

sprintf('%g', 1000000)
#=> "1e+06"
```